# creating a state drop down list

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I know how to create a drop down list, however if you had to create a form where one of the input is a state (a two letter word) in a drop down list, do I just input the state one by one or should I store the state in a DB?

Comment: would you be using the db for anything else?

Comment: well...not really, I have one table in the DB for populating a drop down as well.. but that seems logical as users could add more options to the drop down..

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a table for the states unless you were going to be using it in your db for other purposes. It's overkill otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kinda weird question. Depending on your project of course.

If you need performance and speed, when loading your dropdown list (I'm assuming you meant `<select />`). Then you might want to put them into a separate `.php` file in an array form. So later on you could just loop them with `foreach()`. This method will surely load faster, then to load 50 states from DB.

**inc-states.php:**

```
$states = array(
    1 => 'Alabama',
    2 => 'Indiana',
    3 => 'Nevada'
    // etc..
);
```

**Generate form:**

```
echo '<select name="states">';
foreach ($states as $key => $state) {
    echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $state . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

So after posting you will only save the keys. Later on you can again get the right state via the key:

```
include('inc-states.php')

$user['state'] = 2; // Lets make a default for this example

print $states[$user['state']]; // outputs Indiana
```

Same basic idea remains with the DB method as well. Only this is probably faster.. Unless of course you want to be able to edit the states via some sort of admin console.

**NOTE:** You in fact said two character shortcodes only, but my example array looks prettier with full titles. Anyways, as you probably know, you can put the states in whatever format in the array.

Answer (score 1):

A list of states really aren't updated that often, and it seems like overkill to use a database to store them. I don't know what your backend technology is, but I would likely create a State dropdown control (or whatever passed for a control in your environment) which can be used in multiple locations, so in the rare instance you have to modify your state list, it's only done in a single location. You could also store the states as a list in a configuration system of some kind, but I can't give more details without knowing more about your stack.

Comment: it's PHP, and MySQL is in the db

Comment: In this case you could include() a file which contains your state dropdown. You could put them in a loop as Kalle suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the list in a db, that way if you want to store id's for references instead of saving the state text, it would be easier to manage a relational db that way.

Comment: Storing a 2 character state in your tables is likely only going to take one more byte than if you stored a tinyint referencing a lookup table and it's going to mean that any time you want to see what state someone selected, you have to join to a lookup table. In this trivial instance, I don't think normalization is desirable.

Comment: In a DB, two characters take up less space than an ID.  It would be faster, simpler, and use less space to store the two letters than store an ID and link to the table that has two letters.

Comment: Very true, I have a states database, and in that db, i have state codes, state full name, ID, Lat, Long,.... etc.  If you are only using the two letters, than yes, I agree, it would not make sense to store them in the database, with an id.